# How to excecute allure inside python file?

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I have a question,

- I can't call allure from python when I using

  os.system("allure " + "serve " + 'link_path_report')
  or
  subprocess.run(['allure serve link_path_report'])

cmd show "'allure' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

but when I manual input command to cmd it's work ok

Comment: Use the full path of allure. It's something like /usr/bin/allure.

Answer (score -1):

In this case I use subprocess to call allure command in power shell

```
subprocess.run([r'powershell.exe', r'allure ' + 'serve ' + './Reports'])
```